# Firestore update function not working with collectionGroup

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update a document in firestore, but I get
"Unhandled error TypeError: res.docs[0].update is not a function\n"
when i don't use collectionGroup but instead i get the doc by id the update function works fine.
Here is my code:

```
await db.collectionGroup('campaigns').where('campaignId', '==', data.campaignId).get()
        .then((res: any) => {
            res.docs[0].update({status: data.status}).then((result: any) => {
                    return {success: true}
                },(err: any) => {
                    return {success: err};
                });
            return {success: true};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `docs` collection in a `QuerySnapshot` contains `DocumentSnapshot` objects. To be able to call `update()` you need to have a `DocumentReference`. To get from the document snapshot to a reference, call `ref` on it.

So:

```
res.docs[0].ref.update(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem ultimately stems from using `any` in your types as discouraged by [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any) and many [blog posts](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/typescript-stop-using-any-there-s-a-type-for-that). It effectively "switches off" TypeScript and then you may as well be using plain JavaScript. You should also avoid calling variables `res` or `result` and instead call them something closer to what they are such as `doc` for a `DocumentSnapshot` or `querySnapshot` for a `QuerySnapshot`.

The Firebase SDKs export all of their types, `res` in your `then()` handler will be given the `QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>` type automatically and where you used `update()` an error would be shown.

`res.docs[0]` will be a [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot)(when you have a result!), which doesn't have a `update()` function. To access `update()` for this document, you need it's reference, which can be obtained using `res.docs[0].ref`.

So to fix

```
res.docs[0].update({status: data.status})
```

you would change it to

```
res.docs[0].ref.update({status: data.status})
```

However, in your current code, you also don't chain the promises correctly which means your errors won't be handled correctly.

```
await db.collectionGroup('campaigns').where('campaignId', '==', data.campaignId).get()
  .then((res: any) => {
    /* need return here */ res.docs[0].update({status: data.status}).then((result: any) => {
        return {success: true}
      }, (err: any) => {
        return {success: err};
    });
    return {success: true}; // instead of here
  });
```

You can help pick up these types of problems by rearranging your code:

```
await db.collectionGroup('campaigns')
  .where('campaignId', '==', data.campaignId)
  .limit(1) // if you are only using 1 result anyway, may as well request just 1.
  .get()
  .then((qSnapshot) => {
    return qSnapshot.docs[0].ref
      .update({ status: data.status })
  })
  .then(
    () => {
      return { success: true }
    },
    (err) => {
      return { success: err }
    }
  );
```

When considering how to rewrite your lines for readability, consider the following structure:

```
starterLocation   // firebase.firestore() or db.collection("someCollection") or someRef (a variable containing a Reference object)
  .child()        // this would be as many .collection() or .doc() as needed
  .child()
  .filter()       // this would be as many .orderBy(), .where(), .startAt(), etc as needed
  .filter()
  .operation()    // this would be get() or onSnapshot() for queries,
                  // or set(), update(), delete() for references
```

You would then handle it's result using traditional [Promise chains](https://web.dev/promises/) (remember to check your returns!) or the newer [`async`/`await` syntax](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions) as you desire.

Using the above code as an example:

```
await db.collectionGroup('campaigns')            // the starter location
  .where('campaignId', '==', data.campaignId)    // a filter
  .limit(1)                                      // another filter
  .get()                                         // the operation
  .then((qSnapshot) => {                         
    return qSnapshot.docs[0].ref                 // the starter location
      .update({ status: data.status })           // the operation
  })
```